# CMD is not recognising VM environment variable in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, environment-variables, dockerfile

We have a dockerfile that uses both `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` to execute a script and start our java application respectively. It contains other information, but essentially looks like this:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/home/config/wait-for-elastic.sh", "http://localhost:9200", "home/config/createElasticIndex.sh"]

CMD java -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=0.0.0.0:9700,server=y,suspend=n -jar -Dlog4j.configurationFile=/home/config/log4j2.yaml application.jar --spring.config.name=application,kafka --spring.config.location=/home/config
```

This have been working fine, until today when I went to add some encryption libraries (Jasypt) to our project to secure our passwords. Having setup the application to use Jasypt, I now have to add the following arguement to my `CMD` command to provide the application the master password like so `-Djasypt.encryptor.password=password`. I've tested that using this, the container can run fine without issue. However this is obviously not very secure providing the password in plaintext through the command. So I've added the password as an environment variable called `JASYPT_ENCRYPTOR_PASSWORD` into the container via my Kubernetes deployment.yaml file. I've also verified this exists within the container by using `printenv`.

```
CMD java -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=0.0.0.0:9700,server=y,suspend=n -jar -Djasypt.encryptor.password=$JASYPT_ENCRYPTOR_PASSWORD -Dlog4j.configurationFile=/home/config/log4j2.yaml application.jar --spring.config.name=application,kafka --spring.config.location=/home/config
```

But this then results in the container crashing with an `EncryptionOperationNotPossibleExeception`. It looks like the command is using the the word $JASYPT_ENCRYPTOR_PASSWORD as opposed the value of the environment variable itself. I do not understand why this is happening. I have tried a number of different approaches, such as using `CMD` with an array of arguments like

```
CMD ["java", "-Xdebug", "-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=0.0.0.0:9700,server=y,suspend=n", "-jar", "-Djasypt.encryptor.password=$JASYPT_ENCRYPTOR_PASSWORD", "-Dlog4j.configurationFile=/home/config/log4j2.yaml", "application.jar", "--spring.config.name=application,kafka", "--spring.config.location=/home/config"]
```

But that seems to crash with other errors about the formatting being incorrect. So I am stuck as to how to resolve this.

I was able to get it to work by switching from using `CMD` to `ENTRYPOINT` with the above command like so

```
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-Xdebug", "-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=0.0.0.0:9700,server=y,suspend=n", "-jar", "-Djasypt.encryptor.password=${JASYPT_ENCRYPTOR_PASSWORD}", "-Dlog4j.configurationFile=/home/config/log4j2.yaml", "application.jar", "--spring.config.name=application,kafka", "--spring.config.location=/home/config"]
```

But this then creates a problem where I can't have 2 `ENTRYPOINT` commands in the same Dockerfile.

Can anyone help with why the CMD command doesn't recognise the VM environment variable?

EDIT: Also if it's important, this container is being deployed to a Minikube environment via a normal Kubernetes deployment yaml file with the `kubectl apply` command.

EDIT 2: How I set the env variable in the deployment.yaml file:

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-app
  lables:
    app: my-app
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: my-app
        image: my-image
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        volumeMounts:
        - name: my-app-logs
          mountPath: /home/logs
        env:
          - name: JASYPT_ENCRYPTOR_PASSWORD
            value: "password"
```

EDIT 3:
I've found something unusual. If I change my CMD command to be

```
CMD ["/bin/sh", "-c", "java -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=0.0.0.0:9700,server=y,suspend=n, -jar -Djasypt.encryptor.password=$JASYPT_ENCRYPTOR_PASSWORD -Dlog4j.configurationFile=/home/config/log4j2.yaml application.jar --spring.config.name=application,kafka --spring.config.location=/home/config"]
```

and remove the `ENTRYPOINT` line, everything works fine, because the environment variable is being read correctly. I've verified this by simply running `CMD ["/bin/sh", "echo $JASYPT_ENCRYPTOR_PASSWORD"]` which prints "password", which is the correct value. However if I add the `ENTRYPOINT` line back in, then everything crashes again since the env var is being read in as an empty string. I have no idea why changing the CMD command the one above works different the one I had before.

EDIT 4: I believe I've narrowed this down to being an issue with how I'm using the `CMD` and `ENTRYPOINT` commands, due to not understanding how they interact with one another when run in the same way. I've found [this link](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-cmd-and-entrypoint-interact) in the docker documentation, but still don't fully understand how to use it in my case after reading it.

Comment: I'd expect your very first form to work, except that it would get an empty string as the property value.  Are you using a `docker run -e` option to pass the environment variable into the container?  It won't otherwise see it on its own.

Comment: I don't believe we are using `docker run -e`. These containers are deployed using Minikube (cut down version of K8s). I did see when I tried to assign the VM environment variable to another environment variable within the Dockerfile, that it was coming up blank. But then it worked fine when I changed it to `ENTRYPOINT`, so I presume the container must be able to see the variable value?

Comment: @DavidMaze I've just checked our deployment file and for that container I do set the environment variable up. So it should be available inside the container at runtime

Comment: In the Kubernetes YAML descriptor, are you setting `command:` or `args:` (overriding `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD`, respectively)?

Comment: We are not doing either of those in the deployment.yaml file. I've edited my question to show a sample of how we are setting it up and setting the environment variable

Comment: @DavidMaze I've found something unusual. If I change my `CMD` command to be `CMD ["/bin/sh", "-c", "java -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=0.0.0.0:9700,server=y,suspend=n, -jar -Djasypt.encryptor.password=$JASYPT_ENCRYPTOR_PASSWORD -Dlog4j.configurationFile=/home/config/log4j2.yaml application.jar --spring.config.name=application,kafka --spring.config.location=/home/config"]` and remove the `ENTRYPOINT` line, everything works fine. However if I add the `ENTRYPOINT` line back in, then everything crashes again since the env var is being read in as an empty string. I am so confused